# How to display image from image browser in telerik editor

Tags: jquery, telerik-mvc

I have customized the telerik editor shown in the image.  I want to display the clicked image in a div showing in black box.

so how can i display clicked image in a black box.

[image: This is the customize telerik editor so how can i display clicked image from image browser in a black box showing in right side.]

This is the li tag

```
<li data-type="f" data-uid="7ac480cd-8d8c-4a34-80b3-58b3b48467c9" class="k-tile k-state-selected" role="option" aria-selected="true">
  <div class="k-thumb">
    <img alt="1.jpg" style="" src="ImageBrowser/Thumbnail?path=1.jpg" class="k-image">
  </div>
  <strong>1.jpg</strong> <span class="k-filesize">206.97 KB</span> 
</li>
```

And I have applied this jQuery to get the image source from li element.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
   $('li.k-state-selected').live("click", function () { 
      var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src"); alert(src); 
   }); 
 });"
```

Comment: anyone please guide me on this that how can i do this.

Comment: just grab the image src, create a new img element with that src and append it to that div

Comment: But there is a problem in getting image source

Comment: which is? I don't see the img tag, can you expand the DOM tree a little more? is the image used as a background in CSS?

Comment: also, please post what you've already tried

Comment: This is the li tag <li data-type="f" data-uid="7ac480cd-8d8c-4a34-80b3-58b3b48467c9" class="k-tile k-state-selected" role="option" aria-selected="true"><div class="k-thumb"><img alt="1.jpg" style="" src="ImageBrowser/Thumbnail?path=1.jpg" class="k-image"></div><strong>1.jpg</strong> <span class="k-filesize">206.97 KB</span> </li>
And i have applied this jqeury to get the image source from li element.
"  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li.k-state-selected').live("click", function () {
            var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
            alert(src);
        });
    });"

Comment: well, besides using a deprecated jquery function (talking about `live()`), I don't see the problem with that code. What does the alert box display?